# Best method to manage metadata about tags in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, tags, metadata

I am using MongoDB and I would like to add tags to documents.

In my application I have few groups of users. I want to allow only users of the same group to share tags about a document with each other, I do not want people from other groups to see the tags.

I need to support adding tags, removing tags and finding tags (either any operator or all - meaning i need to mach all tags in a given list, or just one from a given list)

Currently I am doing it like this:

```
{ _id: someID,
  tags: ["A", "B", "C"]
  tags_metadata: [ { "user"  : "userFoo",
                     "group" : "groupA",
                     "tag"   : "A"},
                   { "user"  : "userBar",
                     "group" : "groupB",
                     "tag"   : "B"}
                   { "user"  : "userFoo",
                     "group" : "groupA",
                     "tag"   : "C"}
                  ]
 }
```

If i need to search for tags ["A", "B"] for userFoo in groupA what I would do is

```
db.find({"tags" : {"$all" : ["A","B"]})
```

and then in the application I would go through the tags_meatadata on the cursor and make sure all of tags ("A", "B") are tagged by people from my group.

Is this a good way to go about doing this task? 
Is there a better one I should consider 
(Right now I'm only indexing tags, so i get the mongo query fairly quickly, and hoping the tags_metadata is not too big)

Thanks.